# How to use chroot'd desktop environment on Android with external display, mouse and keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, android, chroot, desktop-environment

I have a chroot'd Arch Linux environment set up on my Android phone (a OnePlus One) and I would like to connect it to a monitor (directly or with use of some sort of passthrough/adapter eg. Raspberry Pi), mouse and keyboard to use as a desktop. How can I do this with low latency? (and preferably high quality)

I have tried VNC over USB tethering to a Raspberry Pi, but there is a lot of latency when a large portion of the screen has to be redrawn at one time, eg. web browsing.

Also, note that my phone has neither Slimport or MHL.

Thanks!

Comment: Good Question, but this is a weird configuration, so it may take awhile.

Comment: @eyoung100 Yeah I thought it would be handy to be able to this when I'm away from my main computer.

Comment: Have you tried VNC directly to a laptop/desktop? Wondering if it could be the pi slowing things down.  On the computer, do an `adb forward tcp:5900 tcp:5900`, and then connect VNC localhost. Another option is X forwarding if you have OpenSSH installed. FWIW, Linux in a chroot has traditionally been relatively slow for me (not latency)... Have done this for several years. I'm doing it now on a Note 3 (Quad core + 3GB RAM) and it is surprisingly slow.  I use an app called XServer XSDL for display & plug a keyboard/mouse directly into its USB OTG port.

Comment: ... it _is_ handy though, and usable enough when you don't have a computer.  A third option would be a USB OTG to HDMI connector if your phone supports it, and an external keyboard/mouse. You'd probably need a self-powered hub to get all those devices connected though

Comment: @transistor1 Yes unfortunately as I said there is no Slimport or MHL support on the OPO and I think VNC or some similar remote desktop-like solution is the only way. Also, I think the bandwidth over ADB is slower than USB tethering because 'adb push' gave me only around 4000KB/s whereas I was getting around 16000 - 20000KB/s over tether, although I could be wrong there. Finally, yes I think the Raspberry Pi might be a bottleneck as the same setup to my laptop running Debian proved to be a fair amount faster.

Comment: Sorry -- I missed your point on Slimport/MHL because I wasn't familiar with the terms. It seems logical that tethering would be faster than ADB.  Does this phone have built-in USB tethering?  What do you use to do the tethering?  If you want to get adventurous, one thing I have played with in the past is building a custom kernel that runs an [Ethernet Gadget](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_ETH.html), which causes your phone's USB port to act like an interface.  It blocks other functions of the USB port, so you can't use ADB with it, but it _may_ be faster...

Comment: @transistor1 Yes, my phone has built-in tethering and that's what I'm using. (I think it's available on most Android phones these days, you can just go into Settings and switch it on) It's nice because you can use ADB, charge and tether all at the one time, and I built ADB for the Raspberry Pi to send commands. I had not heard of Ethernet Gadget, but I'll certainly have a look!

Comment: Some carriers (like mine) restrict built in tethering, which is one reason for using the Ethernet Gadget.  If you're using the built-in tethering, as opposed to an app or "hackish" method, I doubt you'll see much of a gain, if any. In any case, [here](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/frontpage/compilinggnexkernel/#Downloading_from_GIT_repository_for_ICS_and_Compiling) are some minimal notes I took while playing with this a while back. YMMV. Good luck! If you do find a faster way to do VNC in your travels, please answer your own question - I'd love to know also!